# How to know whether my app is installed on a mobile?

Tags: android

I am creating an app.In this app when user signs up all of that user's contacts will be invited.My problem is x has two numbers of y say y1 and y2.When x sent invitation to y and y installed my app on his/her mobile with the number of y1.After that y shouldn't get any invitation not only from x but also from any of his contacts.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try thid code to know your app is installed or not

```
     boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.check.application");  

    if(isAppInstalled) {
        //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.check.application");
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        Log.i("Application is already installed.");       
    } else {
        // Do whatever we want to do if application not installed
        // For example, Redirect to play store

        Log.i("Application is not currently installed.");
    }
}

private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, please add some description about the answer , so that other also know what actually it is and how it works. Thanks

Comment: where to use this code . . . i mean in which class ??

Comment: Use can use this code in any class ..may be click on any button or anywhere

Comment: ok . . but the class would run this code only after the installation. . . then how this would check whether the app is installed or not. . . bcz it is already installed on the device.